# Laravel - Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables, **users** and **pictures**. The tables have a many-to-many relationship and I have created a pivot table name **user_pictures**.

The users table is as follows:

```
id
firstname
lastname
```

The pictures table is as follows:

```
id
filename
url
```

The user_pictures table contains:

```
id
user_id
picture_id
```

When a user adds a picture, the picture *filename* and *url* is stored in the **pictures** table, and in the **user_pictures** table the *picture_id* of that picture is stored alongside the *user_id* of that user.

How can I retrieve all the picture *filename* and *url* related to the user that have added them using Eloquent ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    // Define pictures with a pivot table link
    public function pictures() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\UserPicture', 'user_pictures', 'picture_id', 'user_id');
    }
    //add methods
}

class UserPicture extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_pictures';
    public function picture() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Picture', 'id', 'picture_id');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
    //add methods
}

class Pictures extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pictures';
    //add methods
}
```

If you don't want to add timestamps to the tables you must add these 2 methods:

```
 public function setCreatedAt($value) {
        // to disable created_at
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt($value) {
        // to disable created_at
    }
```

To fetch pictures from a user do this:

```
$userPictures = UserPicture::where(array('user_id'=>1)->get();
foreach($userPictures as $userpicture) {
    $picture = $userpicture->picture();
}
```

Comment: How to I loop through in my UserController to get all the pictures related  to the user id?

Comment: `$user = User::where('id', 1)->get();`
 `$user will contain its details like --`
`$user->['id'] = 1`
`$user->['name'] = "Your Name"`
`$user->['pictures'] = _array_of_user_pictures_`

Therefore loop through `$user->['pictures']`

Comment: I added the image retrieval to my answer

Answer (score 0):

In your `User` model add the following relation

```
public function pictures() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Picture::class, 'user_pictures');
}
```

In your `Picture` model add the follwing relation

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class, 'user_pictures');
}
```

Then to get all pictures associated with a user

```
$pictures = $someUserObject->pictures;
```